# java array sort() manual realization

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have an array of objects, which have to be sorted by their fields. Sorting algorithm must be written manually. I've chosen merge sort, but can't understand, how to compare by different fields. Made classes with Comparator implementation, but don't understand, how to select which one has to be called.

Object class:

```java
public class Ball{
    private int size;
    private int weight;
    private String color;

    public Ball(int size, int weight, String color) {
        this.size = size;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

}
```

Comparator classes:

```java
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortByWeight implements Comparator<Ball> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Ball o1, Ball o2) {
        if(o1.getWeight()<o2.getWeight()){
            return -1;
        }
        if(o1.getWeight()==o2.getWeight()){
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortByColor implements Comparator<Ball> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Ball o1, Ball o2) {
        return o1.getColor().compareTo(o2.getColor());
    }
}
```

Sorting algorithm class:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TypeMergeSort {
    public static Ball[] mergeSort(Ball[] list){
        Ball[] buffer1 = Arrays.copyOf(list, list.length);
        Ball[] buffer2 = new Ball[list.length];
        Ball[] result = mergeSortInner(buffer1, buffer2, 0, list.length);
        return result;
    }
    public static Ball[] mergeSortInner(Ball[] buffer1, Ball[] buffer2, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (startIndex >= endIndex - 1) {
            return buffer1;
        }

        //already sorted
        int middle = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2;  //middle index
        Ball[] sorted1 = mergeSortInner(buffer1, buffer2, startIndex, middle);  //left part mergeSort recursion
        Ball[] sorted2 = mergeSortInner(buffer1, buffer2, middle, endIndex);    //right part mergeSort recursion

        //merge
        int index1 = startIndex;
        int index2 = middle;
        int destIndex = startIndex;

        Ball[] result = sorted1 == buffer1 ? buffer2 : buffer1;

        //in origin it was a code for int comparrison
        //select value to push
        while (index1 < middle && index2 < endIndex) {
            result[destIndex++] = sorted1[index1] < sorted2[index2]
                    ? sorted1[index1++] : sorted2[index2++];
        }
        //move left index
        while (index1 < middle) {
            result[destIndex++] = sorted1[index1++];
        }
        //move right index
        while (index2 < endIndex) {
            result[destIndex++] = sorted2[index2++];
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

How should I fix it? Thx in advance

Comment: Let me make sure that I understand your question. You have an array of `Ball` objects and you want to sort that array by the `weight` attribute and if two `Ball`s have the same `weight` then you want to sort them by the `color` attribute. If that is correct, then you want to compare the `color` as a string. In other words "green" comes before "red" which comes before "white". Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a `Comparator` parameter to the merge sort functions.

```java
public static Ball[] mergeSort(Ball[] list, Comparator<Ball> comp){
    Ball[] buffer1 = Arrays.copyOf(list, list.length);
    Ball[] buffer2 = new Ball[list.length];
    Ball[] result = mergeSortInner(buffer1, buffer2, 0, list.length, comp);
    return result;
}
public static Ball[] mergeSortInner(Ball[] buffer1, Ball[] buffer2, int startIndex, int endIndex, Comparator<Ball> comp) {
    if (startIndex >= endIndex - 1) {
        return buffer1;
    }
    int middle = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2;
    Ball[] sorted1 = mergeSortInner(buffer1, buffer2, startIndex, middle, comp); 
    Ball[] sorted2 = mergeSortInner(buffer1, buffer2, middle, endIndex, comp);
    // ...
}
```

Then, use `Comparator#compare` to find the relative ordering inside `mergeSortInner`.

```java
while (index1 < middle && index2 < endIndex) {
    result[destIndex++] = comp.compare(sorted1[index1], sorted2[index2]) < 0 ? sorted1[index1++] : sorted2[index2++];
}
```

Finally, create an instance of your custom `Comparator` when calling `mergeSort`.

```java
Ball[] sorted = mergeSort(arr, new SortByWeight());
// this sorts the array by the weight field of each Ball
```

You could also use the `Comparator.comparing` methods to define custom `Comparator`s more succinctly.

```java
Ball[] sorted = mergeSort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt(Ball::getWeight));
```